# User Folders in SQL server management studio Databases node

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server management studio Under Databases node, there is only one folder node as 'System Database'. It contains all the system databases. 
Is it possible to create User Folders to contain user databases? I would like to group many of my databases according to their purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to reorganize the object explorer tree structure in SQL Server without a third-party component.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [SQL Handy Groupie](http://www.skilledsoftware.com/)